# MacOS X - compiling a plugin

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang, qmake

My application can load plugins. Plugins can use symbols from the main executable.

It is written in C++ with Qt. I'm using the qmake to build it.

Under Linux there's a weak linking, which allows my plugins to be compiled and linked without satisfying all symbol dependencies (which will be provided by the loading application at runtime anyway).

Windows requires all symbols to be satisfied. I managed to do that with mingw32 with help of `-Wl,--export-all-symbols,--out-implib,libMyApp.a`, which produces a table of symbols from the executable to be used by the linker when linking the plugin.

Now I've got a problem with MacOS X. I don't know how to deal with it. I found at Apple's help [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/porting/conceptual/portingunix/compiling/compiling.html) that I should compile my plugin not with `-dynamiclib`, but instead I should use `-bundle -bundle_loader MyApp`. Problem is that qmake forces `-dynamiclib` and I don't know how to disable it. I also don't know if using this "bundle" options will help with my problem.

What is the proper way to build such plugin using qmake?

EDIT/UPDATE:
I use qmake from within QtCreator. The `-dynamiclib` is provided (and forced) by qmake automatically when compiling a `TEMPLATE = lib`. When the `-dynamiclib` is provided to the compiler, it says I cannot use `-bundle_loader` together with `-dynamiclib`. The message stands that it's forbidden. Therefore I'm looking for a way to remove that `-dynamiclib`.

Yes, I have read the qmake manual. Not "word by word", but generally I've looked for my problem in there, with no luck.

I use Qt/qmake 5.3.1, QtCreator shipped together with Qt package (3.1.2).

Comment: you should be able to use a dynamiclib

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What IDE do you use? Which version of Qt/qmake? Have you read qmake manual http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-manual.html ?

Comment: Wouldn't a better (cross-platform) architecture be to load the plugin dynamic library/shared object and pass the function pointers to the plugin rather than relying on linking?  Surely that would work better?

Comment: @trojanfoe: The problem is that plugin should have access to numerous (easly over 100) symbols, including classes, data types. Sticking to function pointers causes huge overhead for implementing special facades to hide datatypes, etc.

Comment: That makes sense.  Could that stuff be put into a separate library, used by both app and plugins?

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yeah, I was thinking about that too. If nothing else solves the problem, that probably will be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-common-projects.html)

> When using the lib template, the following options can be added to the CONFIG variable to determine the type of library that is built:

**plugin**  -   The library is a plugin; this also enables the dll option.

So, try to add into your .pro file

> ```
> macx:{
>     CONFIG += plugin
>     QMAKE_LFLAGS_SHLIB  -= -dynamiclib
>     QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN -= -dynamiclib
>     QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN += -bundle
> }
> ```

Similarly you can control compilation flag for your project.

Additional information about qmake variables can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html).

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I don't know how I missed it. I'll try it at home and accept the answer once it's confirmed to work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything, at all. I looked at compilation commands performed and they're all the same, including the problematic `-dynamiclib`.

Comment: @Googie could you please provide short example? It can be simple project with your .pro file on github. Another option - invest some time in CMake build tool http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_library. QtCreator integrates with it nicely.

Comment: My project is quite big and I don't want to spend too much time on developing a short example. I think I'll go another way - one that trojanfoe mentioned in comments to my question. Thanks for your effort anyway. I'd be happy to give you the reputation points, but I would have to accept the answer, which I don't think is the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Googie I've updated my answer and I hope it'll solve your issue.

Comment: That one I've already tried. I guess the `-dynamiclib` is declared somewhere else, but I don't know where. It could be that this flag is not exposed in any of qmake variables, therefore could be unavailable for removal.

Comment: @Googie Could you please try QMAKE_LFLAGS_SHLIB -= -dynamiclib ? I've searched folder with my qt and find that it is only variable which also set this option for mac.

Comment: Good point! I did what you suggested and I still got error, but it made me think about other QMAKE_LFLAGS_* variables. I printed all of them and I noticed that indeed `QMAKE_LFLAGS_SHLIB` adds `-dynamiclib`, but also `QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN` does the same! I removed this option from both variables and I was able to provide `-bundle -bundle_loader` and everything compiled successfly! :) Please edit your answer to include `QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN` and I will accept it.